# Listening to keys interrupts editor opened in terminal

Tags: rust, terminal, command-line

In the following code, a loop checks whether the command has finished or it's still running. If it's still running, you can stop it with Ctrl + C. Note: I'm doing this because when the command is running the terminal is in [raw mode](https://docs.rs/termion/latest/termion/raw/index.html).

```
use std::{process::Command, thread, time::Duration};
use termion::{event::Key, input::TermRead};

pub struct CmdRunner {}

impl CmdRunner {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let mut command = Command::new("script");

        command.arg("-qec").arg("sleep 4 && echo test").arg("/dev/null");

        let mut child = command.spawn().expect("failed to spawn command");
        let mut stdin = termion::async_stdin().keys();

        loop {
            match child.try_wait() {
                Ok(Some(_)) => {
                    print!("Child process has exited\r\n");
                    break;
                }
                Ok(None) => {
                    let input = stdin.next();

                    if let Some(Ok(key)) = input {
                        print!("A key was pressed!\r\n");

                        match key {
                            Key::Ctrl('c') => {
                                print!("Ctrl + C was pressed!")
                                // in the actual code, a condition is set to true here.
                            }
                            _ => {}
                        }
                    }

                    print!("Still running...\r\n");
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    eprint!("Error while waiting for child process: {}", e);
                    break;
                }
            }

            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut command = CmdRunner {};

    command.run();
}
```

This works with commands like `sleep 4 && echo test`, but if you run a command that opens an editor, like `vi`, Temion's key listener will interrupt the editor.

If you change the `run()` function to this:

```
fn run(&mut self) {
    let mut command = Command::new("script");

    command.arg("-qec").arg("vi test.txt").arg("/dev/null");

    let mut child = self.command.spawn().expect("failed to spawn command");
    
    child.wait().expect("editor exited with a non-zero exit");
}
```

Commands like `vi test.txt` will work as expected.

So I should handle normal commands and commands that open an editor separately?

Or maybe I can modify the original code so it also works with commands that open an editor? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way this is handled in Unix applications is that, when a process starts a subprocess that is expected to be interactive rather than background, the *only* thing the parent is doing is waiting for the child. It should not be also reading from stdin — the child should be given exclusive access to stdin.

You will also find that various programs' output will not appear correctly if you are running in raw mode — and they may be *expecting* to receive Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z in signal form, not as raw characters.

The simple solution here is to **exit raw mode before starting the child process**, and don't read stdin yourself while it is running. That way, the child gets the normal behavior of its environment, just as if it had been started directly from a shell. The standard Ctrl-C handling will be able to kill the child process.

If you truly want to intercept Ctrl-C while the program is running then you will need to create a separate **pseudo-tty** to give to the child process, and explicitly copy input to and output from the pseudo-tty. Handle Ctrl-C yourself and pass on all other input to the subprocess. However, this will still interfere with applications such as Emacs which expect to actually interpret Ctrl-C as a command to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. "The simple solution here is to exit raw mode before starting the child process." You mean for both interactive and background sub-processes?

Comment: @alexchenco Only foreground ones (maybe interactive, or might print something), not background ones.